# Не ищется элемент с помощью text(), если название содержит кавычки xpath selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Ищу элемент в браузере с помощью xpath запроса

```
//*[@class = 'CustomFieldValueGroupedList__value']//*[text()='Экран "Рассчитанные цены"']
```

Ввожу этот запрос в среду разработки

```
driver.find_element('xpath', "//*[@class = 'CustomFieldValueGroupedList__value']//*[text()='Экран "Рассчитанные цены"']")
```

Из-за того, что в названии присутствуют кавычки, этот запрос горит с ошибкой.

Как правильно заменить кавычки в данном случае, чтобы запрос отработал?

Comment: Используйте маскирование двойных кавычек - text()='Экран \"Рассчитанные цены\"'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно применить обратные кавычки (`) вместо обычных кавычек ("), чтобы экранировать текст внутри кавычек:

```
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@class = "CustomFieldValueGroupedList__value"]//*[text()="Экран `Рассчитанные цены`"]')
```

Либо можно использовать символ слеша `()` перед кавычками внутри текста

```
driver.find_element('xpath', "//*[@class = 'CustomFieldValueGroupedList__value']//*[text()='Экран \"Рассчитанные цены\"']")
```

Есть еще такие варианты:

Использование апостроф `(')` вместо кавычек в тексте:

```
driver.find_element('xpath', "//*[@class = 'CustomFieldValueGroupedList__value']//*[text()='Экран 'Рассчитанные цены'']")
```

сохранение текста в переменной:

```
search_text = "Экран 'Рассчитанные цены'"
driver.find_element('xpath', f"//*[@class = 'CustomFieldValueGroupedList__value']//*[text()='{search_text}']")
```

метод `translate` для замены:

```
search_text = "Экран \"Рассчитанные цены\""
search_text = search_text.translate(str.maketrans({'"':'\''}))
driver.find_element('xpath', f"//*[@class = 'CustomFieldValueGroupedList__value']//*[text()='{search_text}']")
```